# ListView se corta al consultar servidor remoto con Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-asynctask

Tengo un activity con tabs, y en un fragment de estos tab cargo un list  View, en este fragment tengo una clase que hereda de AsyncTask y lo que hace es traer de una webapi un listado de nombres de personas y la ruta a una imagen que esta en otro servidor, entonces en el Adaptador del ListView cuando configuro el campo nombre, busco la imagen así.

```
imagenb = Utils.getBitmapFromURL("http://servidor.com.ar/imagenes/imagen1.jpg");
```

Esta luego la meto en el `ImageView`.

Lo que me sucede cuando corro la app en el celular, llega a cierto elemento del listview y se corta, y en el log da el siguiente error:

> I/Choreographer: Skipped 388 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread.

Supongo que es porque hace muchos llamados al servidor para traer la imagen, como puedo solucionar esto?
Pense por ejemplo hacer algun proceso por fuera y guardar las imagenes en la bd que consulta la webapi.
O traer la imagen en algun evento del listview , no se si existe algo que al hacer scroll en el llist view vaya trayendo y no todo a la vez.

Bueno espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Lucho a que te refieres con "se corta", termina tu aplicación o que se corta?

Comment: el último elemento del listview no se veia, pense que era porque dejaba de hacer pedidos al servidor, luego me di cuenta que era solo algo de diseño, ya que al listview le simule un espaciado con un borde transparente, esto hacia que el ultimo elemento no se ve, lo solucioné  agrandando el borde bottom del listview.Gracias